# Sanity Check with XPath in Ruby Watir

Tags: ruby, xpath, watir

I'm using the Ruby Watir library to do automated testing for a client and I'm having issues with the XPath selector.  I think I just need another set of eyes to let me know if I'm just missing something.

Here is the selector I'm using:

```
puts ie.cell(:xpath, "//img[@src='3.jpg']/../").text
```

For this set of tables, it works as expected and prints "Third Image":

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="1.jpg">First Image</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="2.jpg">Second Image</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="3.jpg">Third Image</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But is is breaking when I remove the second table:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="1.jpg">First Image</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="3.jpg">Third Image</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Using the puts code above I get this error on the second example:

```
Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException: Unable to locate element, using :xpath, "//img[@src='3.jpg']/../"
```

Comment: Both cases work fine here.  1.8.6 on XP.

Comment: I would recommend to post your question at http://groups.google.com/group/watir-general/ too. 1400+ Watir users there.

Comment: Really strange. I reproduced it too. The strange thing is this:

b.cell(:xpath, "//img[@src='2.jpg']/../").text


=> "Third Image"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduced the problem, and restarting the browser (IE6) fixed it for me.

Comment: Starting a new IE instance did fix the issue.  There are a lot of weird bugs I experienced with this though.  I had an html file on my desktop that I was testing against.  If I modified the html file and refreshed the page, the xpath selector wouldn't work consistently at all.  However, using other selectors, such ad :id would work fine.  Another example of something that wouldn't work is if I changed the src attributes, the xpath selector would not pick up the changes after a page refresh.

Comment: I am not sure what is going on. Sounds like a caching problem. If you want a better answer, post this to watir-general group, there are more people that know their way around Watir there.

Answer (score 1):

For current versions of Watir the better way to do this would be

browser.img(:src => '3.jpg').parent.text